# Clarification on god objects, test type, test coverage, and how to make a class unit-testable

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, domain-driven-design, functional-testing

What I am currently trying to do is to test the constructor of a class in an unit test.

I am not sure whether the instance of this object is a "god object", I would say it's not, since it only aggregates several other components.

Either way, I am open to a better design.

So the rough class diagram looks like this

[image]

`World` is the suspected god class. Its dependencies, `ServiceProvider`, `CommandRegistry`, `EventHub` and `Environment` are injected via its constructor.

In its constructor, `World` does the following things:

1. store its dependencies in private fields
2. register a hook `($this, 'onCommandIssued')` with the `eventHub` so that the `world` receives notifications about all commands being executed not through the `world` instance itself (`world` having also a method `executeCommand`)
3. tell the environment to *adopt* the world: `$this->environment->adoptWorld($this)`. The environment's role is to adapt the world to some of the realities of the running environment, for instance a web environment has some specific services which are not available in a console application environment (e.g. the "session" service)
4. notify via the event hub that the construction of the world has finished: `$this->eventHub->notify(new WorldConstructedEvent($this));`

Maybe this looks like a heavy constructor, but it simply is what is defined as "constructing the world".

The `World` is basically the gateway to send commands (as Data Transfer Objects, via `World::executeCommand()`) to which different services can register hooks.

Now to the problems/questions:

1. I am trying to unit-test this constructor, but I have to add a bunch of `@uses` annotations, which makes it feel like anything else but an unit test. What is it then, a functional test? Unit-testing `World` is awkward, testing anything else is really trivial and I don't see this problem emerging in any other test, which makes me ask myself why that is and how to improve the design.
2. Is `World` a god object? All it does is to aggregate other components and forward calls to them.
3. How to properly unit-test the methods of `World`? If I use lots of stubs and I dependency-inject them, is it still unit-testing?

This is for a domain-driven designed (complex) application and I am open to suggestions which would make the design better (testable and decoupled).

Please let me know in the comments if you need any more details.

As I don't know where this discussion will lead to, I may refine my questions.

Comment: I would think that you would feed a mock EventHub and check that the hook method is called.  Repeat as necessary for the other dependencies.  I suspect I am missing something in your question.

Comment: You mean a stub `EventHub`, right? The tested class is `World`, so that would be the only mock in my case.

Comment: Anyway thanks, it's a good idea.

Comment: Mocks and stubs are not the same: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html . To test your constructor all we care about is that the EventHub and Environment methods are called with the expected arguments.  Being a Mockest Tester (to use the Fowler's terminology), I would mock the dependencies.  You might be more of a classical tester.

Comment: AFAIK mocks are the ones a test asserts against, while stubs are the "mocks" which you inject in the SUT, which the SUT depends on ("a la dependency injection").

Comment: I disagree.  Stubs and mocks are different.  They are both "Test Doubles".  However, no need for a big discussion here.  Maybe some other folks will chime in.

Comment: Yeah, both are test doubles, and that's why I said "mocks" with quotes - as they are not really mocks.

Comment: What is the client code to `World`?

Comment: Why do you want to test constructor ? Is there any behavior in it ? Which intentions do you want to capture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to unit-test the class by setting up proper expectations and mock the dependencies:

```
<?php

namespace Common\World;

use TestFramework\TestCase;

class WorldTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     * @covers \Common\World\World::__construct
     * @uses   \Common\World\World::setEventHub
     * @uses   \Common\World\Event\Adopted
     */
    public function construction()
    {
        /** @var \Common\World\Environment $environmentStub |\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject */
        $environmentStub = $this->getMockBuilder('Common\World\Environment')->getMock();
        /** @var \Common\World\EventHub|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $eventHubStub */
        $eventHubStub = $this->getMock('Common\World\EventHub');

        $environmentStub->expects($this->once())
            ->method('adoptWorld')
            ->will($this->returnCallback(function (World $world) use ($eventHubStub) {
                $world->setEventHub($eventHubStub);
                return true;
            }));
        $eventHubStub->expects($this->once())
            ->method('trigger')
            ->with($this->isInstanceOf('Common\World\Event\Adopted'));
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Common\World\World', new World($environmentStub));
    }

    /**
     * @test
     * @covers \Common\World\World::__construct
     * @expectedException \RuntimeException
     * @expectedExceptionMessage the environment has rejected this world for incompatibility reasons
     */
    public function construction_rejected()
    {
        /** @var \Common\World\Environment $environmentStub */
        $environmentStub = $this->getMockBuilder('Common\World\Environment')->getMock();
        $environmentStub->expects($this->once())
            ->method('adoptWorld')
            ->will($this->returnValue(false));

        new World($environmentStub);
    }


}
```